# Not able to create check button using loop and dictionary in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written python code which list all files in cache folder and create check button on toplevel window

'''

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def buttons():
     #creating top level window 
     top_level = tk.Toplevel()
     top_level.geometry("700x500+500+200")
     top_level.title("select folder files")

     #creating label frame on toplevel window 

     main_body = ttk.LabelFrame(top_level)
     main_body.pack(side = "top",fill = "both")

     #changing current writing directory to cache folder using getcwd() function so that 
     #reaching to cache folder can be independent of platform

     os.chdir(os.getcwd() + r"\cache")

    #listing all files in cache folder

     dirlist  = os.listdir()

    #creating dictionary for storing Boolean value (is button pressed or not) 
     checkbutton_list = {}

    #creating check button using loop
     for item in dirlist:
        
         #defining variable for storing boolean value
         is_selected = tk. BooleanVar()
         check_button = ttk.Checkbutton(main_body,text = item,variable = is_selected)
         check_button.grid(sticky="w")
         checkbutton_list[item] = is_selected
     top_level.mainloop()
buttons()
```

'''
problem I'm facing is that Boolean values are not storing in `checkbutton_list`
when i run loop on `checkbutton_list`
'''

```
for val in dirlist:
    print(checkbutton_list[val].get())
```

'''
it show false. what i want is when user check one of the check buttons, ticked button store true and rest store false.
How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Should `checkbutton[val].get()` be `checkbutton_list[val].get()`? And when the checking be executed?

Comment: _"...values are not storing.."_: Your loop depends on `dirlist`, try `print(dirlist)` and make sure, its not empty.